# How to generate the JWT token using Prisma API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I am using [prisma](https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-server/authentication-and-security-kke4/) to work with the GraphQL. I know there is a way to secure the graphql server with a secret key. For example on specifying the secret key as:

```
secret: my-secret-42
```

in `prisma.yml` , and then running `prisma deploy` will secure the graphql server and all the subsequent queries will need a JWT token to access it.

I am able to generate the JWT token using the command

```
prisma token
```

This gives me the token and on passing it in the headers, I am able to access it. But is there an API using which I could generate the token and I do not have to manually run the `prisma token` command on the CLI.

I want the javascript to directly access the GraphQL via queries. For this, I need some form of authentication to happen. Since there would be multiple users using the application, I want to have different tokens for different users. Thus I am looking for a way where I could generate the token using the API if available with Prisma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service token is a simple JWT token that can easily be created by using service and stage name, as well as the secret. You can create the token yourself and attach it. Take a look at the actual code the prisma CLI is using:

```
  getToken(serviceName: string, stageName: string): string | undefined {
    if (this.secrets) {
      const data = {
        data: {
          service: `${serviceName}@${stageName}`,
          roles: ['admin'],
        },
      }
      return jwt.sign(data, this.secrets[0], {
        expiresIn: '7d',
      })
    }

    return undefined
  }
```

Source: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/blob/master/cli/packages/prisma-yml/src/PrismaDefinition.ts

More information regarding the structure:

Service tokens follow the JSON Web Token (JWT) specification (RFC 7519):

> "JSON Web Token (JWT) is a compact, URL-safe means of representing
>   claims to be transferred between two parties. The claims in a JWT are
>   encoded as a JSON object that is used as the payload of a JSON Web
>   Signature (JWS) structure or as the plaintext of a JSON Web Encryption
>   (JWE) structure, enabling the claims to be digitally signed or
>   integrity protected with a Message Authentication Code (MAC) and/or
>   encrypted."

A JWT has the following three components:

> Header: The header typically consists of two parts: the type of the
>   token, which is JWT, and the hashing algorithm being used (which is
>   HS256 in the case of Prisma service tokens).

```
{   "alg": "HS256",   "typ": "JWT" }
```

> Payload: The payload contains the claims. Claims are statements about
>   an entity (typically, the user) and additional data. Here is what it
>   looks like for a service called demo deployed to the dev stage:

```
{   
   "data": {
      "service": "demo@dev",
      "roles": ["admin"]   
   },   
   "iat": 1532530208,   
   "exp": 1533135008 
}
```

> Signature: The signature is used to verify the message wasn't changed
>   along the way. To create the signature part you have to take the
>   encoded header, the encoded payload, a secret, the algorithm specified
>   in the header, and sign that. For example if you want to use the HMAC
>   SHA256 algorithm, the signature will be created in the following way:

```
HMACSHA256(base64UrlEncode(header) + '.' + base64UrlEncode(payload), secret)
```

Therefore, a JWT typically looks like this: xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz

Source: https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-server/authentication-and-security-kke4/#service-token

Comment: Would you know how to specify the service-name and stage-name with prisma? Is this something to be done in `yml`?

Comment: The service and stage can be defined in your prisma endpoint environment variable, e.g. `PRISMA_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:4466/SERVICE/STAGE"`. See https://www.prisma.io/docs/understand-prisma/how-prisma-works-under-the-hood-j8ff/ in the section "Learn more about the endpoints of Prisma services".